FIt-SNE on google colab
How can I implement the FFT-accelerated Interpolation-based t-SNE (FIt-SNE) on my colab notebook?
I was trying to compute t-SNE on a kaggle dataset of dog emotions,
I tried first to take the first components.
pc = 60
pca = decomposition.PCA(n_components=pc)
_ = pca.fit(images)
imgPCA = pca.transform(images)

tsne = TSNE(n_components=2)
Z = tsne.fit_transform(imgPCA)
plot_embedding(Z)

Then I tried the multicore t-SNE to raise the number of iterations but I still don't like it
!pip install git+https://github.com/DmitryUlyanov/Multicore-TSNE.git

from MulticoreTSNE import MulticoreTSNE

Z = MulticoreTSNE(n_jobs=4, n_iter=10000).fit_transform(imgPCA)
plot_embedding(Z, show_axis = True)

Now I want to try to use the FIt-SNE, but I don't know how to use it, can you help me?
Or maybe you can help to improve the previous snippets of code if you want.
There is the code to understand the format of the dataset:
import pandas as pd
import cv2

img_size = (192,192,3)
num_px = img_size[0] * img_size[1] * img_size[2]

directory = '/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/ML/Dog_Emotion/' 
images = []
labels = []
labels_df = pd.read_csv(directory + "labels.csv")
n_images = 0

for image in tqdm(labels_df.iloc, desc = "loading images", unit = "images", total = 4000):
  images.append(np.asarray(cv2.resize(cv2.imread(directory + image[2] + '/' + image[1], cv2.IMREAD_COLOR), img_size[0:2])[:, :, ::-1]))
  labels.append(image[2])

images, labels = np.array(images).reshape(4000, num_px), np.array(labels)

print(f'labels shape: {labels.shape}')
print(f'images shape: {images.shape}')
print(f'images size: {img_size}')

def plot_embedding(Z, show_axis="False"):
  plt.figure(figsize=(10, 8))
  map = {label: i for i, label in enumerate(np.unique(labels))}
  color = np.array([map[l] for l in labels])
  plt.scatter(Z[:, 0], Z[:, 1], c = color, cmap = "jet")
  plt.colorbar()
  plt.title('2d t-SNE Visualization')
  if not show_axis:
    plt.axis("off")
  plt.axis("equal")
  plt.show()

labels shape: (4000,)
images shape: (4000, 110592)
images size: (192, 192, 3)

PCA and t-SNE often perform better when data is normalised. Before applying PCA, make sure the pixel values are scaled from 0 to 1. This helps to centre the data around zero and standardise the scale.
Choosing 60 components for PCA may be suitable, but you might try different numbers to see how they affect the t-SNE results. Depending on the amount of variance captured, fewer components may be better. For example, you can start with 4 and gradually increase it to 8, 16, 24,... and see which one works best.
Also I need to mention that t-SNE has several parameters you can tweak:
Perplexity: effects how t-SNE balances attention between local and global features of the data. (Typical values range between 5 and 50.)
learning_rate: I think the default is 200, but you may need to adjust it as well.
Try these, I hope you'll like the result more.
